# Angular 5 parametrized component using @Input

Tags: angular, components, angular5

I'm new to Angular and looked around but couldn't find the answer...

How do you pass a parameter to a component (**html**) that is using `@Input` ?

What I'm trying to achieve is quite simple, I have a LogoComponent which I'd like to call from 2 places: the LoginComponent (there it should be full size) and from the DashboardComponent (where its `size` is parametrized) but I'm getting an exception:

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'size' since it
>   isn't a known property of 's-logo'.
>   1. If 's-logo' is an Angular component and it has 'size' input, then verify that it is part of this module.

**logo.component.ts** (simplified for the sake of lisibility)

```
@Component({
    selector: 's-logo',
    template: `<div>{{size}}</div>`,   <----- size would actually set the css height 
})
export class LogoComponent{
  @Input() size: string ;
}
```

**login.component.html** (simplified)

```
<s-logo [size]="100px"></s-logo>
```

I also tried with the syntax, with no luck (double + single quotes):

```
<s-logo [size]="'100px'"></s-logo>
```

Isn't that how I'm supposed to achieve this ?

Comment: Thats the correct way to pass `Input`, but there is no `height` anywhere. I suspect somewhere you do like `<s-logo [height]="100px"></s-logo>`

Comment: have you registered your component with `@NgModule`
  declarations array?

Comment: yes, both are in my app.module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can't bind to 'height' since it isn't a known property

your problem isn't with `@Input size`, it's that your trying to pass in a different variable called `height`.

You will need to make an @Input for `height` as well if it is something your are trying to pass in

Comment: You were right, in some other forgotten file, `<s-logo>` was referring to a wrong variable name... duh!